# (Reference Request) Socle of a module.

Tags: reference-request, noncommutative-algebra, socle

I came across the term "Socle" of a module defined for a finitely generated module $M$ over a noetherian ring $(A,\mathbb{m})$ as follows

$$\mathrm{Soc}(M) = \lbrace x \in m \mid ax = 0\ \forall a \in \mathbb{m} \rbrace.$$

This definition is same as the definition in wikipedia as the sum of simple modules of $M$. I also read that some properties of a module can be read from the socle of a module which i found interesting. Any references towards possibly the proof of statements [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socle_(mathematics)#Socle_of_a_module) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Usually they are to be found among the references from the Wiki page. (I thing the commutative-algebra tag can be replaced by non-commutative algebra as the properties you are looking for are proved for non-commutative tings.)

Comment: Replaced the tag following your advice. Usually the references are numbered after the statements and i didnot find any references for any except the last one.

Comment: @random123 What is a "noetherian ring $(A,m)$"? Do you mean that it is a local ring with maximal ideal $m$?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes. That is what i meant.